# How to get data from /wp-json/wp/v2/users/me

Tags: rest-api

i was trying to get the user data with JWT auth in wordpress.

i was send in the postman get request to /wp-json/wp/v2/users/me with the token that i get from /wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token.

but i get this error:

```
{
    "code": "rest_not_logged_in",
    "message": "you are not logged in",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

can someone help please

Comment: That ought to work I think. How exactly did you send the token?

Answer (score 2):

I was just doing this earlier, if you are trying to simply get user data from your wordpress website with Postman just simply do a request to:
/wp-json/wp/v2/users/

or directly to your user number:
/wp-json/wp/v2/users/User Number here

**(you will need ACF to REST API plugin )** so you can see the endpoint acf field below author and template. **If you use ACF**

It seems that you are trying to get data securely or post data then I would recommend the following:

install: JWT Authentication for WP-API plugin
then edit your
.htaccess and add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

and also add the following to your wp-config.php

```
define('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY', 'any-secret-code-you-want');
define('JWT_AUTH_CORS_ENABLE', true);
```

And finally you will need to send a POST request in Postman to:
/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token with the Header:

```
Content-Type
application/json
```

and the body:

```
{
    "username": "WordPressUserName",
    "password": "WordPressPassword"
}
```

Now Copy the **Token** in your results and create a new POST in Postman
and in the Headers add:
Authorization

```
Bearer **InsertYourToken**
```

And now you should have access to easly GET and POST data from your wordpress website.

you can also follow the video tutorial if you still get stuck, starting form this time:
https://youtu.be/fFNXWinbgro?t=300